# Calling AWS neptune fast reset API using Resttemplate

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, amazon-neptune

I am trying to call POST fast reset API of AWS neptune, using spring Resttemplate as well as using postman, in the both scenario's I am getting below error, not able to figure out, how the API is expecting the request parameters.

1. Using Postman

```
    {
    "detailedMessage": "no gremlin script supplied",
    "requestId": "80c4cb16-0bfc-869a-34ee-f103aa23fdcb",
    "code": "MissingParameterException"
}
```

I am passing the request body as JSON to POST call

```
Request URL https://aws-naptune-host-url:8182
Request Body : 
{
    "action":"initiateDatabaseReset"
}

Header : Content-Type : application/json
```

2. On calling this using spring boot rest template I am facing the same error.

Tried mulitple ways of passing the parameter, as Request Body, Request params, but getting the same result everytime.

**Working condition**
The neptune API is working fine, because I am calling this from terminal/cmd using curl, I am getting response

Curl request

```
curl -X POST https://aws-neptune-host-url:8182/system  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '{ "action" : "initiateDatabaseReset" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the incomplete URL https://aws-neptune-host-url:8182/system, missed **system** keyword on the URL